# How can I get the NT name of a partition in python (Windows)?

Tags: python, pywin32

How can I get the NT name of a partition in python? Or at least a list of all the names in the system?

What I have: a drive letter or a label, or some other identifier of the partition (for example, the letter E:, or label "Data")

What I need: a name like "\\?\\HarddiskVolume12" that corresponds to this partition.

Before anyone asks, yes, I really need it.

The thing is that I need to be able to address partitions with and without letters assigned to them, so the best solution would be to get a list of some kind of objects that have all the IDs, nt names, letters as attributes, and then, based on these, I can choose the partitions that I need for my purposes.

P.S. I tried using FindFirstVolume/FindNextVolume from the winsys._kernel32 module, but that returns some kind of ID with a GUID in it... Not exactly what I want.

Comment: take a look at the os, and platform modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import win32file

win32file.QueryDosDevice('E:')
```

Comment: This works only for letters, but I need it mainly for partitions without letters (for the reason that they're not accessible via a letter)

Comment: win32file.QueryDosDevice(None) gives me a list of all devices... Well, maybe I can use that info to get what I need

Comment: So far this looks like the only way to do it